# Heroku: Error deploying Laravel application (failed to create symbolic link)

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

Based on this article: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/installing-a-laravel-app-on-heroku

Im trying to deploy my app to Heroku but when I do the push I get this error:

```
remote: -----> Preparing runtime environment...
remote: ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./heroku-hhvm-apache2’: File exists
remote: ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./heroku-hhvm-nginx’: File exists
remote: ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./heroku-php-apache2’: File exists
remote: ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘./heroku-php-nginx’: File exists
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to studapp-stage.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/studapp-stage.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/studapp-stage.git'
```

I made this change on Heroku:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!